# On Array of Hashes need to count values while creating other key pairs same time in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I need help counting ocurrences inside the array of hashes "aoh" and producing and expected output "summary".

This is the original data "aoh":

```
aoh = [{:interface=>"1A",
        :host=>"host_1",
        :status=>"online"},
       {:interface=>"1A",
        :host=>"host_2",
        :status=>"online"},
       {:interface=>"1A",
        :host=>"host_3",
        :status=>"offline"},

       {:interface=>"2A",
        :host=>"host_4",
        :status=>"offline"},
       {:interface=>"2A",
        :host=>"host_5",
        :status=>"offline"},
       {:interface=>"2A",
        :host=>"host_6",
        :status=>"online"}
      ]
```

And this is the Expected Ouput

```
summary = [{:interface=>"1A", :online_hosts=> 2, :offline_hosts=> 1},
           {:interface=>"2A", :online_hosts=> 1, :offline_hosts=> 2}]
```

Note: I was trying this code...

```
    summary = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { online: 0, offline: 0 } }
      aoh.each do |item|
        summary[item[:interface]][item[:status] == 'online' ? :online : :offline] += 1
      end
    summary
```

```
=> {"1A"=>{:online=>2, :offline=>1}, "2A"=>{:online=>1, :offline=>2}} # almost, but it is not the expected result
```

and almost this produce the expected result, but this way interface value was moved outside the hash as a key, and hash key names are not the expected. I do really need keep inside the hash the interface key pair also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
aoh.group_by { |h| h[:interface] }
   .map do |k,a|
      n = a.count { |h| h[:status] == "online" }
      { interface: k, online_hosts: n, offline_hosts: a.size - n }
    end
  #=> [{:interface=>"1A", :online_hosts=>2, :offline_hosts=>1},
  #    {:interface=>"2A", :online_hosts=>1, :offline_hosts=>2}]
```

Note:

```
aoh.group_by { |h| h[:interface] }
  #=> {"1A"=>[{:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_1", :status=>"online"},
  #           {:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_2", :status=>"online"},
  #           {:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_3", :status=>"offline"}],
  #    "2A"=>[{:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_4", :status=>"offline"},
  #           {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_5", :status=>"offline"},
  #           {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_6", :status=>"online"}]}
```

---

Another way is to use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the value of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here that block is `do |_,o,n| ... end`. See the doc for the definitions of the three block variables, `_`, `o` and `n`. (`_` holds the common key. I've used an underscore to represent that variable to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation, a common convention.)

```
aoh.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(
    g[:interface]=>
      { interface: g[:interface],
        online_hosts: g[:status] == "online" ? 1 : 0,
        offline_hosts: g[:status] == "online" ? 0 : 1
      }
  ) do |_,o,n|
      { interface: o[:interface],
        online_hosts: o[:online_hosts]+n[:online_hosts],
        offline_hosts: o[:offline_hosts]+n[:offline_hosts]
      }
    end
end.values
  #=> [{:interface=>"1A", :online_hosts=>2, :offline_hosts=>1},
  #    {:interface=>"2A", :online_hosts=>1, :offline_hosts=>2}]
```

Note that the receiver of [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) is:

```
{"1A"=>{:interface=>"1A", :online_hosts=>2, :offline_hosts=>1},
 "2A"=>{:interface=>"2A", :online_hosts=>1, :offline_hosts=>2}}
```

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, this is a little better than the Schwern way because you can change the key name too.

Comment: Is there any difference between with_object and each_with_object?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, `Enumerator#with_object` requires the receiver to be an enumerator; `Enumerable#each_with_object` requires the receiver to be an instance of a class `C` for which `C.included_modules.includes?(Enumerable) #=> true` and has a method `C#each`. Hence, `aoh.with_object({}) #=> undefined method 'with_object' for #<Array:0x00007ff90c274ce8>`...

Comment: ... We could write `aoh.each.with_object({}) #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [{:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_1", :status=>"online"}, {:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_2", :status=>"online"}, {:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_3", :status=>"offline"}, {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_4", :status=>"offline"}, {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_5", :status=>"offline"}, {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_6", :status=>"online"}]:each>:with_object({})>`, which produces the same result...

Comment: as `aoh.each_with_object({}) #=> #<Enumerator: [{:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_1", :status=>"online"}, {:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_2", :status=>"online"}, {:interface=>"1A", :host=>"host_3", :status=>"offline"}, {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_4", :status=>"offline"}, {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_5", :status=>"offline"}, {:interface=>"2A", :host=>"host_6", :status=>"online"}]:each_with_object({})>`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: lchatter, your problem is a good example of one for which there are multiple solutions among which none stands out as being the "best" in some sense. I have given two solutions, @Schwern has given a third. In my view the choice of which to use is purely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thank you very much. That perfectly answers my question. Thanks again for writing such a detail answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to directly build an array of hashes, you have to scan the array every iteration to find the interface's summary. That's awkward and expensive.

Building a hash of hashes is easier and faster. Do the same thing you're doing, but also store the interface name in the summary. Then take the values of the resulting hash.

```
# Same thing, but also store the interface name in the value.
summary = Hash.new do |h, k| 
  h[k] = { interface: k, online: 0, offline: 0 }
end

# Same thing, just easier to read.
aoh.each do |item|
  status = item[:status] == 'online' ? :online : :offline
  summary[item[:interface]][status] += 1
end

# What you want is the values of the hash.
p summary.values
```

Comment: If `item[:status]` is guaranteed then `item[:status].to_sym` might make more sense